# open subset of scheme with zero section

Tags: sheaf-theory, schemes

Let's take a scheme $X$. Is it possible to have an open non-empty subset $U$ of $X$ such that $\mathcal{O}_X(U)=0$?

I can't find an argument against it, since there could exist some open set $V\subset U$ such that $\mathcal{O}_X(V)\ne 0$, or is it impossible too?

It's obvious if $U$ were affine, but in the general case?

Comment: Very original and amusing question!

Comment: Very nice question! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible: every non empty open subset $U\subset X$  has non zero ring of functions: $\mathcal{O}_X(U)\neq 0$ .

Indeed, if   $V\subset U$ is a non empty  open affine subset  we get a restriction morphism of rings $r_{VU}:\mathcal{O}_X(U)\to \mathcal{O}_X(V)$ which is unity-preserving, like all ring morphisms.
Hence $r_{VU}(1_U)=1_V$  and since $\mathcal O_X(V )$ is the  ring of functions of the non-empty affine scheme $V$ we have  $1_V\neq0$, which forces $1_U\neq0$ and thus shows that $\mathcal{O}_X(U)\neq 0$.

Comment: **Unity Preserving** oh god, I keep forgetting it.. thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome, dear Exodd. And don't worry: it took me some time to think of that too, so welcome to the club :-)

Comment: Little notice: I don't know if inside any open subset there exists an affine open scheme, but those two magical words let you conclude anyway, since the stalks of any point inside $U$ is zero, and this is really not possible

Comment: Dear exodd,  anyway yes: inside every open non-empty subscheme there is a non-empty open affine subscheme. The affine open subsets of a scheme actually form a basis of its topology.